# Naming dataframes based on counter iteration in R?

Tags: r

I have a loop that will spit out a bunch of dataframes, and want to name the dataframes based on current iteration of the loop, e.g. `df1` for the first iteration, `df2` for the second iteration, and so on.

However, i'm running into problems trying to use the loop iteration counter to construct the dataframe name.  For example, let's imagine I am in the first iteration of the loop and want to name the dataframe:

```
counter <- 1
as.name(paste("df",counter,sep="")) <- data.frame(x = (1:10), y = (10:1))
```

I get an error

```
Error in as.name(paste("df", counter, sep = "")) <- data.frame(x = (1:10),  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Does anyone know how I might use the counter information to create dataframe names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assign`:

```
assign(paste0("df", counter), data.frame(x = (1:10), y = (10:1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work with assign(paste0("df", counter), data.frame(x = (1:10), y = (10:1)))

Comment: @Thomas Right. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of cluttering the global environment with data frames, it would be best to collect them in a `list`, and then you can use `paste0` to name them in `setNames` with e.g.

```
> dfList <- setNames(list(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1)), paste0("df", 1))
```

after that you can refer to the data frame with

```
> dfList$df1
    x  y
1   1 10
2   2  9
3   3  8
4   4  7
5   5  6
6   6  5
7   7  4
8   8  3
9   9  2
10 10  1
```

As joran notes, if you insist on populating the global environment with these data frames, you can use

```
list2Env(dfList, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

and the data frames will be assigned as objects in the global environment.

Comment: ...and since people doing this sort of thing often _insist_ that they really do need the data frames existing as separate objects, you can always achieve that via `list2env(dfList,envir = .GlobalEnv)` if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I will try this next - I'm currently running my loop (making 22 dataframes) but it's taking some time to complete.  Will try your suggestion next!

Answer (score 3):

This is meant to complement Richard's, as it felt a little too substantial to simply edit into his.

A typical code pattern for this sort of thing would be:

```
#Initialize an empty list of the desired length
dfs <- vector("list",3)

#Fill the list with data frames, naming as we go
for (i in seq_along(dfs)){
    dfs[[i]] <- data.frame(x = runif(5),y = runif(5))
    names(dfs)[[i]] <- paste0("df",i)
}
```

where the use of `assign` is typically frowned upon as bad (stylistically). If the naming of the data frames is very regular, you don't even need to do it in the loop:

```
names(dfs) <- paste0("df",seq_along(dfs))
```

you can do it in a vectorized fashion as above. And as I mentioned below Richard's answer, even though having them all in a list is never worse, and usually better, than having them as separate objects, you can convert the list to separate objects via:

```
list2env(dfs,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you joran, I was able to follow your suggestion to store all of my dataframes in a list.  This keeps everything much cleaner, as I'm just going to summarize these many dataframes into a single dataframe in the end!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
assign("name", dataframe)
```